# ubuntu 16.04 desktop i386 support on repositories, final date

Tags: 16.04, canonical, official-repositories

The support for Ubuntu 16.04 will end at End Of Life date?

I don't have clear the concept. How does this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is till 2020-2022 and not just 2022?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995049/why-the-ubuntu-16-04-lts-is-till-2020-2022-and-not-just-2022)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 desktop i386 (32-bit) will lose community support --the kind provided by AskUbuntu-- in April 2021.

- Most other flavors of 16.04 (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, etc) already reached End of Life in April, 2019.
- Canonical's Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) is a paid service that provides support for the Ubuntu flavor through April 2024.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases for the complete list of all releases, when they were released, and when support will (or did) cease.

Ubuntu 18.04 is the final release of Ubuntu with full i386 (32-bit) support. Newer releases of Ubuntu have a smaller legacy 32-bit library to support older Wine applications games, etc, but lack a complete 32-bit Gnome-based desktop.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases and also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL#Ubuntu_16.04_Xenial_Xerus the end of standard support for 16.04 will be in April of 2021.