# My server is using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS . Honestly, which version is the safest to update to?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, server, updates, 20.04

I'm hosting just few websites + phpmyadmin , my server is using  Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS . As of august 8 2020 , which version is the **safest** to update the server with ?

I'm going to use some CMS systems and other tools soon, so I'm wondering if a version in particular could have better compatibility with most apps. Is there a "more stable" version in terms of compatibility with "recent" apps?

I anticipate: I'm worried that maybe some apps I install later could not be ready for the the very-last version of Ubuntu yet.

.edit: This is a question that can be raised, because version 16.04 was launched years ago (2016), there has allready been a few number of versions since.

Sure, if it's not broken, why fix it ? I'm not an expert but I can only see positive things from moving up from 16.04, as of august 2020.

Hence my question which I found good [information about on this thread](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-most-stable-version-of-ubuntu-till-today) , and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) is now he version I'm going to look more  into. Why wait, when I know I will have more stuff to host, I would rather do it now. *Apparently support or "maintenance" of 16.04.xx will be ended in 2021.*

Comment: How are you defining "safest?" What leads you to believe that Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, which is fully supported and receiving frequent security upgrades, is not safe? If you are using "recent" applications, then you should be using a similarly recent release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Check your system is fully-upgraded; I'd expect your system to report 16.04.7 and not 16.04.6

Comment: Think he is asking if it would safe with his system to upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04.  He does have an 18.04 tag added.

Comment: @user535733  safest: covering the largest number of tools/apps/cms systems and such. 16.04 was launched in 2016, i though it's about time to get an update.  I'm not saying 16.04 is not safe, was curious about next safest / most reliable / compatible version would be . After more research it appears to Ubuntu 18.04. credit for that info goes to the reply on here  https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-most-stable-version-of-ubuntu-till-today

Comment: @guiverc yes you are correct after checking Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, only upgrade production servers to Ubuntu's Long Term Support (LTS) releases and only after the particular release has hit .1 (e.g. 20.04.1). The LTS releases also receive 5 years of updates (10 years of updates with [Extended Security Maintenance](https://askubuntu.com/q/995049) (ESM) which is free for personal use on up to 3 machines) vs. 9 months for non-LTS releases.

Assuming you've only installed things via Ubuntu's repositories, you're almost certainly "safe" to upgrade to 20.04.1.  I've personally never experienced any upgrade incompatibilities and I've been doing rolling upgrades on a few servers since at least 14.04.

If you've installed things manually from .deb files or compiled things, you may want to see if there are newer versions available.