# Where can I find a driver for my pretty old graphic card?

Tags: drivers, graphics, lubuntu

So here is the problem. I have an old computer, probably from 2008. It used to run Windows 7, but over the years the operative system *crashed* (I don't know if that is the right way to call it). 12 years later, I decided to bring it back to life with Lubuntu (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS). The thing is that I can't find drivers for my graphic card.

[This is what the Terminal says when running `lspci | grep VGA`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdRBm.png)

However, when I search for the graphic card model on settings,  [this is what it says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1hFh.png)

I think that the Terminal is the right one, and I hope you can help me find a driver for that model (*Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10)*)

Thanks in advance

PD: I'm not very good at english, so sorry if there is anything wrong in this question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Intel integrated graphics GPUs use the built-in open source graphics driver in Ubuntu. In order to show all the drivers that are available to be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories and are compatible with your hardware, open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Lubuntu 14.04 has more frugal hardware requirements than Lubuntu 18.04. Try installing Lubuntu 14.04 on this computer with [Extended Security Maintenance](https://askubuntu.com/q/995049) (ESM) which is free for personal use on up to 3 machines.

Comment: I couldn't make it work, I think I don't have any available driver to be installed. Anyway, thanks for the answer!