# MacBook Pro 9,1 hangs on bootup

Tags: dual-boot, startup, macbook

I am installing Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop, onto my MacBook Pro Late 2012 - 9,1. I have played with Linux before but consider me a relative newbie.
When I boot an Ubuntu live USB it works perfectly, but when I installed it from the same USB onto my SSD then I restarted, it  begins the boot process, gets to:

```
.... 
systemd-timedated.service
[  OK  ]  Finished  Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
snapd.seeded.service
[  OK  ] Started Disk Manager.
udisk2 service
NetworkManager-wait-online.service
cups-browsed.service
whoopsie.service
kerneloops.service
gdm.service
```

Then it hangs.

[image: Verbose listing]

Comment: Sorry, I am installing the desktop 22.04 LTS. Just downloaded it today and installed. I used Balena to transfer the ISO onto a USB.

Comment: This is what I downloaded - the desktop 
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=22.04&architecture=amd64
Thanks

Comment: I resolved it by downloading  the earlier version 20.04 and it boots up fine now. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu boots to a black screen problem was solved by installing Ubuntu 20.04 on the  MacBook Pro 9,1 instead of Ubuntu 22.04. It might be a good idea to extend the security maintenance on Ubuntu 20.04 from April, 2025 to April, 2030 by enabling free [Extended Security Maintenance](https://askubuntu.com/a/995053/).